# coldfusion tinymce spellchecker not working / showing

Tags: coldfusion, tinymce

I have an existing tinymce set up working well, using tinymce version 3.4.9 but for some reason the spellchecker is not showing, in fact when I add the spellchecker to the plugins list, the tinymce disapers alltogether.

Below is the cffunction code...

```
<cffunction name="adminEditTinyMCEJS" output="true">
<cfif listLen(tinyMCE_list) gt 0>
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
        tinyMCE.init({ 
          mode : "exact", 
          elements : "#tinyMCE_list#", 
          content_css : "css/tinyMCE.css",
          plugins : "style,table,searchreplace,paste,spellchecker", 
          visual : "true", 
          external_image_list_url : "js/tinyMCE_image_list.js",
          trim_span_elements : "false", 
          valid_elements : "+a[id|style|rel|rev|charset|hreflang|dir|lang|tabindex|accesskey|type|name|href|target|title|class|]" + 
            ",-strong/-b[class|style],-em/-i[class|style]," + 
            "-strike[class|style],-u[class|style],##p[id|style|dir|class|align],-ol[class|style],-ul[class|style],-li[class|style],br," + 
            "img[id|dir|lang|longdesc|usemap|style|class|src|onmouseover|onmouseout|border|alt=|title|hspace|vspace|width|height|align]," + 
            "-sub[style|class],-sup[style|class],-blockquote[dir|style],-table[border=0|cellspacing|cellpadding|width|height|class|align|summary|style|dir|id|lang|bgcolor|background|bordercolor]," + 
            "-tr[id|lang|dir|class|rowspan|width|height|align|valign|style|bgcolor|background|bordercolor],tbody[id|class]," + 
            "thead[id|class],tfoot[id|class],-td[id|lang|dir|class|colspan|rowspan|width|height|align|valign|style|bgcolor|background|bordercolor|scope]," + 
            "-th[id|lang|dir|class|colspan|rowspan|width|height|align|valign|style|scope],caption[id|lang|dir|class|style],-div[id|dir|class|align|style]," + 
            "-span[style|class|align],-pre[class|align|style],address[class|align|style],-h1[id|style|dir|class|align],-h2[id|style|dir|class|align]," + 
            "-h3[id|style|dir|class|align],-h4[id|style|dir|class|align],-h5[id|style|dir|class|align],-h6[id|style|dir|class|align],hr[class|style]," + 
            "-font[face|size|style|id|class|dir|color],dd[id|class|title|style|dir|lang],dl[id|class|title|style|dir|lang],dt[id|class|title|style|dir|lang]",
          theme : "advanced", 
          force_p_newlines : true,
          theme_advanced_toolbar_location : "top", 
          theme_advanced_toolbar_align : "left", 
          theme_advanced_resize_horizontal : false,
          theme_advanced_resizing : false,
          nonbreaking_force_tab : true,
          apply_source_formatting : true,
          theme_advanced_buttons1 : "bold,italic,underline,separator,spellchecker", 
          theme_advanced_buttons2 : "",
          theme_advanced_buttons3 : "",
          spellchecker_rpc_url : "tinymce/jscripts/tiny_mce/plugins/spellchecker/rpc.cfm"


        }); 
    </script>
</cfif>
```

I have implimented the  Plugin spellchecker (for ColdFusion) by Richard Davies - Version: 2.0.4. but this does not have any effect. [download here](http://sourceforge.net/tracker/index.php?func=detail&aid=1908279&group_id=103281&atid=738747spellchecker)

Any help would be much apriciated.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure I have an "answer" for you. But the reasons that it might not show up are:

1. case sensitivity
2. Bad pathing (plugin in the wrong place).
3. Wrong Idendifier (paste,*spellchecker*... instead of "spellchek" for example).

Open Firebug or Charles and take a look at resources that are being called but failing. I'm guessing you will get a clue from that.

Comment: Hi, many thanks, but sadly, none of these are working. would you know of a conflict between the spellchecker and coldfusion?

Comment: I can't think of a CF reason that the button would not show up and the editor would simply fail to show. I don't think tinyMCE actaully does anything with the code. When you click on the spellcheck button THEN the code is in play.... but I could be wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You have a small error in your **valid_elements** option. On the first line of that value, the **+a** element rule ends with a pipe character after the **class** attribute:

```
valid_elements : "+a[id|style|rel|rev|charset|hreflang|dir|lang|tabindex|accesskey|type|name|href|target|title|class|]" +
```

Try removing it so it ends **class]** and not **class|]**. This seems to be enough to stop the SpellChecker from working, although for me the TinyMce instance still loads ok, so I'm not sure this is the issue for you.

Otherwise I'm finding the SpellChecker plugin you're using works fine with Adobe ColdFusion 9.0.1 - it is written specifically for CF, but the docs don't say which versions are supported.